# Should special (simpler) cases have separate code paths?

Tags: coding-style

I have a rather complex method which can get called in two possible "scenarios". One is a special case of the other in which all the nested `foreach` loops are only executed once and several `if` statements are false such that essentially only two lines of code nested deeply inside the method are actually executed.

Now the question is: Should I provide a separate (simpler) code path for the special case even though the complex code handles that case just as well?

I suppose the code would be more readable/understandable that way but I don't want to give the impression that the two cases are handled differently.

Performance is not an issue here so the fact that a simpler code path might also execute faster is negligible.

Example code:

```
foreach(...)
{
    foreach(...)
    {
    ...
        if(...)
        {
            ...
        }

        Something();
    }
}
```

as compared to

```
if(SpecialCase)
{
    Something();
}
else
{
    foreach(...)
    {
        foreach(...)
        {
        ...
            if(...)
            {
                ...
            }

            Something();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By essentially duplicating some logic you create redundancy. This is an opportunity for bugs.

> I suppose the code would be more readable/understandable that way

No, because now readers have to understand one more thing than previously. They still have to understand the full algorithm to see what happens in case `!SpecialCase`.

> I don't want to give the impression that the two cases are handled differently

Well, you *are* giving that impression. This is going to be confusing to others.

Consider just adding a comment:

> "In case of SpecialCase the following algorithm is equivalent to Something();"

Answer (score 0):

To me it would be a balance of costs.  Would the extra development & maintenance cost be justified by the saved run-time cost?  You say "performance is not an issue," so you would be increasing expenditure with no payback.  Don't do it.